# IOS/Objective-C: Change property in View Controller from shared instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

A view controller in my app accesses some data from the web via a class accessed through a shared instance. This class performs various server calls.

Based on what is retrieved, I would like to change something in the viewcontroller which has an outlet property wired to a label. To accomplish this, in the shared instance class, I alloc init the class associated with the view controller in storyboard and then set the outlet property. However, the following is not changing anything on screen.

//code in a file accessed via shared instance

```
    IDImportFacebookVC *vc= [[IDImportFacebookVC alloc] init];
        if (_contactCount==0) {
            NSString *emptyMessage = @"No friends found";
            vc.emptyMessage.text = emptyMessage;
        }
```

Is there something else needed?  Also, I think this is probably a complete violation of MVC so would appreciate any suggestions on a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: is that your actual code? You are creating a new instance of  `IDImportFacebookVC `. is that the same instance that you expect to change property?

Comment: It is the same VC.  The original instance is in Storyboard.  No question, it is squirrely, seems to violate MVC and, moreover, is not working.  I guess I could send out a notification but that sounds like a lot of overhead.  There must be a simple way to do this.

Comment: at what point you have data from server ? it is best to update iboutlets in viewdidload. i dont know where are you updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new view controller, you are not accessing the one that is being displayed on screen. The one that is on screen (if it is already on screen) already has an instance that has been initialized. If it is not yet on screen, the OS will initialize one from the storyboard and will not use the one you have just initialized. Even as is, the one you initialize will not do as you are expected cause it has no frame, nor is it set in a window or a navigation controller.

In my opinion, your options are either sending out a notification as you said in the comment, or simply adding a property to your shared instance that contains the data you want to display on screen.

If you are sure that once the screen is shown this data will be available, then the property way works, where you can just set the UI element based on the property of the shared instance. If you are not sure when the data will be available, then the notification will also probably be necessary.

Comment: I went with the property approach, setting it in the shared instance and just grabbing it in viewwillappear of the view controller. while deleting the code above. This solved the problem.

Comment: @user6631314 nice. I'm glad I could help. Thanks for the upvote and accepted answer